# Access several user controls from Child Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, windows-forms-designer

In my Windows Form, I fill a `flowLayoutPanel` with instances of user control `UCDetail`. Something like this:

```
public ParentForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dataGridView1.DataSourceChanged += dataGridView1_DataSourceChanged;
    DT = GetAllRooms(); // DT is one column [RoomNum] w/ 5 rows (201-205)
    dataGridView1.DataSource = DT;

}

private void dataGridView1_DataSourceChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
    flowLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        UCDetail ucb = new UCDetail(row, this.dataGridView1);
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(ucb);
    }
    flowLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout();
}
```

UCDetail has a Click event, so that when the UC is clicked, `ChildForm` is displayed. I pass a reference of the clicked UCDetail so that I can control the properties of the controls in the UC. Something like this:

```
private void UCDetail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var form = new ChildForm(this);
    form.ShowDialog();
}
```

And finally, `ChildForm` has a button with a clicked event that changes `LabelName.Text` in the clicked `UCDetail`. Something like this:

```
UCDetail _cell;
public ChildForm(UCDetail Cell)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _cell = Cell;
}

private void buttonChangeLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _cell.labelEmp.Text = "John Smith";
}
```

So let's say that a user clicks on *RoomNum 202*, the instance of UCDetail for that row is sent to `ChildForm`, and when I click on button in `ChildForm`, `ParentForm` will display *John Smith* for `RoomNum 202`. No issues there.

The problem is that `ChildForm` will now include several TextBoxes so that I can enter several RoomNumbers whose `labelEmp` will change.

Using the previous example, I clicked on *202*, which displays `ChidForm`. In the new textboxes I will type in 203, 205 because I also want to change those rooms to "John Smith".

In `ChildForm` I only have access to 202 (it was clicked), but not to 203, 205 or any other RoomNum that wasn't clicked. How can I change the properties for those controls?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend to read this: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/889332/Many-Questions-Answered-at-Once-Collaboration-betw

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll read it after I find a solution to the issue I'm having.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up passing `flowLayoutPanel1` as reference. It worked well.